# Typescript destructure returned values from function which can be either void or an object

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I use a package that has a function with the following declaration:

```
const getList: (params?: ListRequestParams | undefined) => Promise<void | {
    items: any[];
    pageInfo: PageInfo;
}>
```

I tried to destructure the returned value from a call to this function with:

```
const {items, pageInfo} = await getList(some_param);
```

but it does not work probably due to the 'void' part.  Using a temp value works, but looks clumsy.

```
const temp = await getList(some_params);

if(temp !== undefined)
{
  const { items, pageInfo } = temp;
}
```

Just wonder there is better ways for destructuring in this case.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the behavior that it always returns a value when a `params` object is passed and returns `void` when there are no `params`, or are the arguments and the return type unrelated?  If they are related then we can tackle this by applying a better type to the function (through declaration merging or wrapping it).

Comment: They are unrelated.  getList reads data from a remote server which may not return any data (network errors, ...).  My code is only a small part in a project and I do not want to make changes to the function prototype.

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code (although I would use a better name than `temp` such as `response` or `result` :D), you can't destructure something which could be `void`. The suggestion of using a type like `Maybe` which was given by Romain Deneau is also a nice idea as it lets you ignore the fact that a value could be null/undefined until a later moment when you can use a method like `valueOrGet` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-maybe-type#valueorget-method)

Comment: I'm new to JavaScript/TypeScript and just wonder if there are some fancy one-liner type castings to destructure the return into either two valid objects or two 'undefined's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, we can't destructure `void`/`undefined` and it's a good thing: it's necessary to handle also the case when `void` is returned, in your example with a guard clause `if not undefined then ...`

If you want your code to focus on the happy path and avoid temporary variable, you can use the `Maybe` type ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-maybe-type)) and its method `map()`:

```
Maybe
  .ofNullable(await getList(some_params))
  .map(({ items, pageInfo }) => { /*...*/ });
```

Comment: I'll stick with temporary var.  It's more readable.  But nice to learn about the Maybe type.  Thanks.